# How can i split this linked list int this way

Tags: c

I got a linked list ***l*** and a number ***x***.This function it is supposed to go to list ***l*** and when the value of the node of the list is lower then ***x*** put that value in list ***mx***, otherwise put the value in list ***Mx***.

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int value;
    struct lligada *next;
} *LInt;


void splitQS (LInt l, int x, LInt *mx, LInt *Mx){
    LInt *aux1,*aux2;
    aux1=mx;
    aux2=Mx;
    while(l){
        if(x<l->value){
            (*aux1)=(LInt)malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
            (*aux1)->value=l->value;
            aux1=&((*aux1)->next);
        }
         if(x>=l->valor){
            (*aux2)=(LInt)malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
            (*aux2)->value=l->value;
            aux2=&((*aux2)->next);
        }
        l=l->next;
    }
}
```

I tested with this output:

**x=2**

List **l=[1,3]**;

and the output expected was **mx=[1]** and **Mx=[3]**

Although, i got this

**mx=[3]** and **Mx=[1]**

I can't figure it out why this is happening.

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) and there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 1):

That's just what you programmed.
In the case `if(x<l->value)`, which means the list's value is greater than `x`, then you put it to `aux1`, which is `mx`. Therefore, big values end up in `mx` and smaller values end up in `Mx`.

To spot mistakes like these more easily, I recommend to use longer and more expressive names, e.g. `smallerValues` and `biggerValues` instead of `mx` and `Mx`. Also, I don't see the point why you're copying the pointers `mx` and `Mx` to `aux1` and `aux2`. You could just use `mx` and `Mx` directly.

Besides, I guess your code does not compile. You use `if(x>=l->valor)`, but `LInt` does not have a member `valor` ;)

<strike>Also, This will probably not run for more than one element per output list. You set `aux1=&((*aux1)->next);` without having `next` initialized. Therefore, after that instruction, `aux1` just points "somewhere".</strike>

**Edit**: Indeed, I was confused by the typedefed pointer as @David C. Rankin said :)

Here is a refactored but entirely untested version:

```cpp
typedef struct {
  int value;
  ListItem* next;
} ListItem;

void splitList(ListItem *inputList, int threshold, ListItem **smallerItems, ListItem **biggerItems) {
  while(inputList) {
    if(inputList->value < threshold) {
      *smallerItems = (ListItem*)malloc(sizeof(ListItem));
      (*smallerItems)->value = value;
      smallerItems = &((*smallerItems)->next);
    }
    else {
      *biggerItems = (ListItem*)malloc(sizeof(ListItem));
      (*biggerItems)->value = value;
      biggerItems = &((*biggerItems)->next);
    }
    inputList = inputList->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: i use aux1 and aux2 because mx and Mx need to be in the beginning of the list after the program is finished.Thanks for your help

Comment: They will be. If you change `mx` or `Mx` in the function (not `*mx` or `*Mx`), it won't have an immediate effect on the pointer outside. E.g. you can have `T* x;` and a function `void foo(T** y) { y = NULL; }`, you can call `foo(&x)` without `x` being changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition inside the `if` statement is wrong, it should be:

```
    if(x>l->value){
        (*aux1)=(LInt)malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
        (*aux1)->value=l->value;
        aux1=&((*aux1)->next);
    }
```

Plus, you don't have to write the second if, you can use `else` instead.

```
void splitQS (LInt l, int x, LInt *mx, LInt *Mx){
    LInt *aux1,*aux2;
    aux1=mx;
    aux2=Mx;
    while(l){
        if(x>l->value){
            (*aux1)=(LInt)malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
            (*aux1)->value=l->value;
            aux1=&((*aux1)->next);
        }
        else{
            (*aux2)=(LInt)malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
            (*aux2)->value=l->value;
            aux2=&((*aux2)->next);
        }
        l=l->next;
    }
}
```